# aliasing a variadic template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, c++14

I have a variadic function like :

```
void test(int){}

template<typename T,typename...Args>
void test(int& sum,T v,Args... args)
{
    sum+=v;
    test(sum,args...);
}
```

I want to alias it to something like :

```
auto sum = test;//error : can not deduce auto from test
int main()
{
    int res=0;
    test(res,4,7);
    std::cout<<res;
}
```

I tried using `std::bind` but it doesn't work with variadic functions because it needs placeholders ...

Is it possible to alias a variadic function ?

Comment: `auto sum = [](auto&&... pp) { return test(std::forward<decltype(pp)>(pp)...); };` or something like that. It's not a true alias, though; for example, you can't use `auto x = &sum<int, double>;`.

Answer (score 4):

In C++1y :

```
#include <iostream>

void test(int){}

template<typename T,typename...Args>
void test(int& sum,T v,Args... args)
{
  sum+=v;
  test(sum,args...);
}

template<typename T,typename...Args>
decltype(test<T, Args...>)* sum = &(test<T, Args...>);

int     main(void)
{
  int   res = 0;
  sum<int, int>(res, 4, 7);
  std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively wrap it in another variadic function and `std::forward` the arguments :

```
template<typename T,typename...Args>
void    other(int&sum, T v, Args&&... args)
{
  test(sum, std::move(v), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I doubt type deduction will work for this "alias".

Comment: @dyp Currently it does not with the usual compilers, but maybe some day not so far :)

Comment: Hmm I doubt the syntax for *variable templates* will support this; since the template defined has no patterns to match with the arguments of the function call. Consider specializations of the variable template. Only in very restricted contexts could a variable template be seen as an alias, and the compiler had to look "through" this layer of abstraction.

Comment: `std::forward<T>(v)` is not necessary since `T v` is not a universal reference. `std::move(v)` is sufficient.

Comment: @dyp updated :) As for the deduction i agree with you although an obvious case to try automatic deduction is when an operator() is called on a variable template which means it is most likely a callable which might be totally deduced by that call. But i'm not a compiler writer so this is total speculation ^^

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is not much different from

```
void test(int)
{
}

void test(double, int)
{
}

auto a = test;
```

There is no way for the compiler to detect which overload you want to use.

You can be explicit about which `test` you want to assign to `a` by:

```
auto a = (void(*)(int))test;
```

If you want to add the variadic template version to the mix, you can use:

```
template<typename T,typename...Args>
void test(int& sum,T v,Args... args)
{
    sum+=v;
    test(sum,args...);
}

auto a = test<int, int, int>;
```

Comment: BTW for this case, if he wanted `test(double, int)`, he could do this: http://ideone.com/KFJnjh

Comment: I know that , I was looking for a way for alising variadic function. @dyp solutions seems working with gcc 4.9 ,http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3aabbd801efe463

Comment: It is not answering the question.BTW `auto a = test<int, int, int>;` does not works : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c19105de2b3d597

Comment: For three arguments, you use `auto a = test<int, int>`

Comment: @awesomeyi I need something that works in general case, my question was just simplified version of my code,I can't use auto for all of the possible ways !

Answer (score 0):

This is not aliasing.`auto a = test` tries to declare a variable a with the same type as `test` and make them equal. Since test isn't a single function, but a function template (and on the top of that you can even overload functions), the compiler can't decide on what the type of a should be.

To alias a template, or as a matter of fact any symbol, you can use the `using` keyword.

```
using a = test;
```

Edit: sorry this one only works for types not functions.

Comment: you can't alias a template function with using !

Comment: Yeah, my bad, you can alias a functor though. Well then it's impossible currently in C++.