# aliasing a std template function

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple

I need to alias `std::get` function in order to improve readability in my code.

Unfortunately I got a compile-time error `get<0> in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type`. `using` is equivalent to `typedef` so it needs types to work with.
I am using a `std::tuple` to represent some data type:

```
using myFoo = std::tuple<int,int,double,string>;
using getNumber = std::get<0>;
```

I look at some previous questions but the solution proposed is to wrap and use `std::forward`. I don't want to write such code for each member.

- [Q1 from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330300/aliasing-a-variadic-template-function)
- [Q2 from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864125/c11-how-to-alias-a-function)

Is there a way to get around this using only *using keyword*?

Comment: "so is their a way to get around this using only _using keyword_?" No.

Comment: You can not use simultaneously `c++11`,`c++14`,`c++1z`, be specific․

Comment: is there any proposal than to change this?

Comment: Is [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Rl3GULuqtIyhfqgr) what you are looking for? If so, I'll put it in an answer. It isn't with `using`, instead it uses a constexpr variable.

Comment: not exactly. but I think I will use it if I don't find sth else very soon.
it's mentioned in a comment in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330300/aliasing-a-variadic-template-function](this).

Comment: @chedynajjar Not the same. In C++17 you have constexpr lambdas. Much better in your case. See my answer.

Comment: @skypjack, ok, true.

Comment: If you find yourself giving names to components of a tuple, perhaps it's a good time to re-evaluate good old structs.

Comment: @n.m. I didn't want to write 11 classes, so I thought it will be faster to alias tuples.

Comment: So now you are writing more aliases than there are classes you have avoided writing, you need to ask around how to write them, *and* your code is still less readable than with plain structs.

Comment: @n.m. writing classes which just has only getter and setter is (IMO) longer than using aliases.

Comment: Here we go again. You don't write classes with getters and setters for each data member. You write a **struct**.

Answer (score 10):

> is there a way to get around this using only using keyword?

I would say *no*, for `std::get` is not a type (thus it's not eligible for such an use).
Moreover, even if it was possible, note that `std::get` is an overloaded function, thus you would have been required to bind yourself to a specific implementation.

That said, in C++17, you can do something like this:

```
#include<tuple>
#include<utility>

using myFoo = std::tuple<int,int,double>;
constexpr auto getNumber = [](auto &&t) constexpr -> decltype(auto) { return std::get<0>(std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)); };

template<int> struct S {};

int main() {
    constexpr myFoo t{0,0,0.};
    S<getNumber(t)> s{};
    (void)s;
}
```

As you can see, `constexpr` lambdas and variables help you creating compile-time (let me say) *wrappers* you can use to rename functions.

---

As correctly pointed out by @T.C. in the comments, if you want to generalize it even more and get an almost perfect alias for `std::get`, you can use a variable template:

```
template<int N>
constexpr auto getFromPosition = [](auto &&t) constexpr -> decltype(auto) { return std::get<N>(std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)); };
```

Now you can invoke it as it follows:

```
S<getFromPosition<0>(t)> s{};
```

See it on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/D9kiNSPANIbf4vI6).

Comment: This is a generic lambda. A templated function would work just as well

Comment: @n.m. C++17 is somehow intriguing. :-)

Comment: For extra fun, make it a variable template, and you get something really close in syntax to OP's version, just with `using` spelled `constexpr auto` instead.

Comment: @T.C. Nice catch. I'm adding it to the answer (with credits).

Comment: I was more thinking about naming the variable template `get`, and then you can do `constexpr auto getNumber = get<0>; constexpr auto getString = get<1>;` etc.

Comment: @T.C. Oh, OK. Well, I'll leave anyway also the other solution. It's really a close alias for `std::get` now. Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a `using` + an `enum`:

```
#include<tuple>

using myFoo = std::tuple<int,int,double>;

int main() {
    constexpr myFoo t{0,0,0.};
    enum { Number = 0 };
    using std::get;

    auto&& x = get<Number>(t);
    (void)x;
}
```

Although unfortunately, this is not DRY since you have to maintain an enum and a tuple simultaneously.

In my view, the most DRY and safest way to achieve this is to use tagged values in the tuple. Limit the tuple to maximum one of each tag type.

The tag is essentially a mnemonic for some unique concept:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

//
// simple example of a tagged value class
//
template<class Type, class Tag>
struct tagged
{
    constexpr tagged(Type t)
        : value_(t) {}

    operator Type&() { return value_; }

    operator Type const&() const { return value_; }

    Type value_;
};

struct age_tag {};
struct weight_tag {};
struct height_tag {};

using Age = tagged<int, age_tag>;
using Weight = tagged<int, weight_tag>;
using Height = tagged<double, height_tag>;

int main()
{
    constexpr auto foo1 = std::make_tuple(Age(21), Weight(150), Height(165.5));
    constexpr auto foo2 = std::make_tuple(Weight(150), Height(165.5), Age(21));
    using std::get;

    //
    // note below how order now makes no difference
    //

    std::cout << get<Age>(foo1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << get<Weight>(foo1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << get<Height>(foo1) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << get<Age>(foo2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << get<Weight>(foo2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << get<Height>(foo2) << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
21
150
165.5

21
150
165.5
```

Comment: I think you should delete `template<int> struct S {};` or did you put it on purpose?

Comment: @chedynajjar ah yes, I took skypjack's answer as a crib.

Comment: @chedynajjar second approach now fully DRY

Comment: very clean solution considering the lack of aliasing function. I would prefer getting some feature filling this gag, maybe introducing a new keyword to alias only function would be cool.

Comment: @RichardHodges You have to pay fees for the crib!! :-)

Comment: @RichardHodges Ahahahah. Just joking. Paid back, it wasn't necessary. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In general, `tuple` should be used in generic code.

If you know field 1 is a Number or a Chicken, you shouldn't be using a `tuple`.  You should be using a `struct` with a field called `Number`.

If you need tuple-like functionality (as one does), you can simply write `as_tie`:

```
struct SomeType {
  int Number;
  std::string Chicken;

  auto as_tie() { return std::tie(Number, Chicken); }
  auto as_tie() const { return std::tie(Number, Chicken); }
};
```

Now you can access `SomeType` as a `tuple` of references by typing `someInstance.as_tie()`.

This still doesn't give you `<` or `==` etc for free.  We can do that in one place and reuse it everywhere you use the `as_tie` technique:

```
struct as_tie_ordering {
  template<class T>
  using enable = std::enable_if_t< std::is_base_of<as_tie_ordering, std::decay_t<T>>, int>;

  template<class T, enable<T> =0>
  friend bool operator==(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
    return lhs.as_tie() == rhs.as_tie();
  }
  template<class T, enable<T> =0>
  friend bool operator!=(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
    return lhs.as_tie() != rhs.as_tie();
  }
  template<class T, enable<T> =0>
  friend bool operator<(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
    return lhs.as_tie() < rhs.as_tie();
  }
  template<class T, enable<T> =0>
  friend bool operator<=(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
    return lhs.as_tie() <= rhs.as_tie();
  }
  template<class T, enable<T> =0>
  friend bool operator>=(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
    return lhs.as_tie() >= rhs.as_tie();
  }
  template<class T, enable<T> =0>
  friend bool operator>(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
    return lhs.as_tie() > rhs.as_tie();
  }
};
```

which gives us:

```
struct SomeType:as_tie_ordering {
  int Number;
  std::string Chicken;

  auto as_tie() { return std::tie(Number, Chicken); }
  auto as_tie() const { return std::tie(Number, Chicken); }
};
```

and now

```
SomeTime a,b;
bool same = (a==b);
```

works.  Note that `as_tie_ordering` doesn't use CRTP and is an empty stateless class; this technique uses [Koenig lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) to let instances find the operators.

You can also implement an ADL-based `get`

```
struct as_tie_get {
  template<class T>
  using enable = std::enable_if_t< std::is_base_of<as_tie_get, std::decay_t<T>>, int>;

  template<std::size_t I, class T,
    enable<T> =0
  >
  friend decltype(auto) get( T&& t ) {
    using std::get;
    return get<I>( std::forward<T>(t).as_tie() );
  }
};
```

Getting `std::tuple_size` to work isn't as easy, sadly.

The `enable<T> =0` clauses above should be replaced with `class=enable<T>` in MSVC, as their compiler is not C++11 compliant.

You'll note above I use `tuple`; but I'm using it *generically*.  I convert my type to a tuple, then use tuple's `<` to write my `<`.  That glue code deals with tie as a generic bundle of types.  That is what `tuple` is for.

Comment: What's `use_tie_for_operations`?

Comment: @T.C. It is a class that brings the `==` operations into ADL lookup territory, thus auto-implementing `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>=` and `>` for you with one line of code per class you need it in, in an alternate universe before I renamed the type to `as_tie_ordering`.